# Drupal email wraps path

Tags: email, url, drupal, path, word-wrap

I am sending an email from my Drupal website using the hook_mail().

My problem is that the folder where the report is saved into has spaces in its name "to keep folder" and the email's body wraps exactly in the middle of the name of that folder EX:

```
Please visit \\folder1\folder2\to keep
folder to see the report.
```

I was asked to make the "\folder1\folder2\to keep folder" internal path a link if possible or to at least force the whole path to stay on one line.

I tried the url() function like this:

```
$message['body'][] = 'Please visit ' . url('\\\\folder1\folder2\to keep folder') . ' to see the report.';
```

but still it will not show up as a link.

Here is my entire hook_mail() function:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_mail().
 */
function my_module_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
  switch ($key) {
    case 'email_success':
      $message['headers']['Bcc'] = 'my_email@mydomain.com';
      $message['subject'] = 'Successfully generated the report';
      $message['body'][] = 'The daily budget report has been generated.';
      $message['body'][] = 'Please visit ' . url('\\\\folder1\folder2\to keep folder') . ' to see the report.';
      break;

    case 'email_fail':
      // Build the other email
      break;
  }
}
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Your emails are probably being sent in plain text. Try contrib module [**Mime Mail**](https://www.drupal.org/project/mimemail) allowing you to receive emails in HTML.

Via **configuration > system > mimemail**, choose your preferred *E-mail format* & try your `hook_mail` again.